# Need to know which custom UIViews are within a tap

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating custom UIImageViews and placing on a UIImageView in a UIScrollView. When the user taps on the custom UIImageView, it presents a popover.

The issue i may have is if two of the custom UIImageViews are overlapping. I need to ask the user which one he wants.

how can i tell which custom UIImageViews are within a tap? I need each view to return itself if it detects a tap. If more then one view returns, then i can ask the user which one he wants.

each custom UIImageView has a UITapGestureRecognizer created:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(select)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;

[self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

right now, only the top most custom UIImageView is getting the tap and displaying the popover.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you planned on identifying which image was which, but for this example I've used tags. The following will receive the location of a touch within the scroll view, and compare that point to frames of the image views in the scrollviews subviews. It will then add the tags of the images that matched to a mutable array.

**NOTE:** If you don't empty this array when you dismiss the alert new objects will be continuously added to it.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:myScrollView];

    for (UIImageView *myImageView in myScrollView.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImageView.frame, location)) {
            [someMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myImageView.tag]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing touchesBegan: in the view controller but it is never called. In my scroll view, i did add a UITapGestureRecognizer. Would that be intercepting touchesBegan? userInteractionEnabled is set to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by your question that the views are transparent so the user can see that in fact there is overlap, and may intentionally tap the area of overlap.

In any case what you need to do in this case is get the location of the tap:

```
[tapGesture locationInView:scrollView]
```

Then walk the scrollView's subView array, getting each of your UIImageView's, getting its frame, and seeing if the tap is inside that frame.

Now you have an array of possible images - you can pop an action sheet (whatever) and ask the user which to show.

Comment: the user can add a point either where he tapped or based on his GPS. if he adds twice based on his GPS, i end up with two points overlapping each other. i need a way to detect when they overlap so the user can choose which one he wants.

Comment: The comment "two points overlap" is not possible - what do you mean?

Comment: bah, sorry, i've named the custom/subclassed UIImageViews PointImageViews, or points for short.

Comment: But my answer tells you exactly how to do this - you compare the point of interest to each frame, and if you get more than one 'point in frame' you know you have to ask the user about which to use. This was in the original answer. If what you want is to allow the user to tap somewhere that hits a view, and even it that tap doesn't touch two views, but the view that is tapped might overlap another. then take the first view that you find with the point inside, the compare it all all other views seeing if there is overlap (there is a CGGeometry function to do the test for you)